# Bind parameters from checkbox of form with GET method in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a from like below

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    <input type="radio" name="sort" value="date-desc" checked>
    <input type="radio" name="sort" value="price-desc">
    <input type="radio" name="sort" value="price-asc">
    <input type="radio" name="sort" value="like-desc">
    <input type="radio" name="sort" value="like-asc">
    <input type="checkbox" name="show-discount">
    <input type="checkbox" name="show-new">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search">
</form>
```

it returns url like: `<site>?sort=date-desc&show-discount=on&show-new=on`

i want to bind it to the controller action, the action is like below:

```
public ActionResult Index([Bind(Prefix = "sort")]string Sort, 
    [Bind(Prefix = "show-discount")]bool? ShowDiscount = null, 
    [Bind(Prefix = "show-new")]bool? ShowNew = null)
{

}
```

the problem is `ShowDiscount` and `ShowNew` parameter always null (didn't bound properly).

i think the problem caused by the checkbox when checked it written as `cb-name=on` instead of `cb-name=true`. and also when the checkbox unchecked it will not written on the url.

is there a proper way to do this?

and is there a way to map `Sort` parameter to enumeration?

Comment: Use a view model and strongly typed html helpers and let MVC do it all for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a view model

Model

```
public class MyModel
{
  public string sort { get; set; }
  public bool show-discount { get; set; }
  public bool show-discount { get; set; } // or bool? if you want it to be nullable
  public bool show-new { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Edit()
{
  MyModel model = new MyModel();
  model.date-desc = "date-desc"; // set default
  return View(model)
}

public ActionResult Edit(MyModel model)
{
  .... // model is correctly bound with selected values
```

View

```
@model MyModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  .....
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.sort, "date-desc", new { id = "date-desc" });
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.sort, "price-desc", new { id = "price-desc" });
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.sort, "price-asc", new { id = "price-asc" });
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.sort, "like-desc", new { id = "like-desc" });
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.sort, "like-asc", new { id = "like-asc" });
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.show-discount);
  @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.show-new);
  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search">
}
```

Note you can make `sort` and enum. If the bool values are nullable, `CheckBoxFor` will render a dropdown list with 3 values (to allow selection of null)

Note also in your code you do not need the `[Bind(Prefix..`. You could have used `<input type="checkbox" name="show-discount" value="true">` but this would only work for non-nullable booleans since unchecked checkboxes do not post back. If you leave it unchecked you would get `null`, not `false`

**Edit**

If you want to use an enum

```
public enum MyEnum
{
  date-desc,
  price-desc,
  ....
}

public class MyModel
{
  public MyEnum sort { get; set; }
  ....
```

View (include @using for the assembly where you have defined the enum)

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.sort, MyEnum.date-desc, new { id = "date-desc" });
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.sort, MyEnum.price-desc, new { id = "date-desc" });
....
```

Comment: thank you for your response, by using `value="true"` on checkbox like you suggested is working now. second question, is it possible to bind radio button `Sort` with enum instead of string but keep the value `date-desc, price-desc, price-asc`?

Comment: Yes, you can use an enum. I'll update answer shortly (but please get into the habit of using a view model and strongly typed html helpers - you will never have these problems)

Comment: `(but please get into the habit of using a view model and strongly typed html helpers - you will never have these problems)` i used view model binding well, but it is a special case and its a long story :) waiting for the update :)

Comment: OK, I've update answer based on using a view model. If you don't want that you can always convert the string to an enum using `Enum.TryParse()`

Answer (score 0):

Create a `ViewModel` that will contain properties that match your form inputs.

```
public class ViewModel 
{
    public bool ShowDiscount { get; set; }
    // add additional properties
}
```

Then, in your `form` on the `view`, add `@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ShowDiscount)`

```
<form action="/" method="get">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.ShowDiscount)
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Search">
</form>
```

Be sure to let the `view` know which type of `model` it should be expecting. At the top of the `view` specify.

```
@model YourNamespace.ViewModel
```

Your `controller` method will now look like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(ViewModel v)
{
    // do work here.
}
```

The framework will do the binding for you.

Comment: thank you for your response, i know the view model binding well but i don't like the binding with default property name, my action will be called from outside website and it should be able to call from a form via get method. it is about eye candy thing.